# Is it OK if I do not take the receipt in Germany?

Tags: legal, germany, money

During a business trip in Düsseldorf I have bought some chocolate from a rather fancy store. After paying for it I was asked if I want the receipt (I am almost certain that this happened after it was actually printed) and automatically said "no". This was almost automatic because where I live I am typically asked if I need a full invoice for deducting the expense.

This is rather strange for a Eastern-European person who sees signs like "ask for receipt and keep it until exiting the store" all over the place where I live (this is due to rather high tax-evasion and the government forced all stores to put such signs) and I am wondering if it's OK not to ask and keep the receipt in Germany.

**Question:** Is it OK if I do not take the receipt in Germany?

Comment: OK from what point of view? Politeness? In case you’re stopped by security on leaving the store and asked for proof of purchase?

Comment: @Traveller - I am mostly interested in the legal part (your second question).

Comment: So does the sign in the store say “Ask for the receipt and keep it until exiting the store (this is due to rather high tax evasion)” or does it say “Ask for the receipt and keep it until exiting the store”? If it’s the latter, it seems to me it’s a warning that you might need it to prove you paid for the goods. Otherwise you might spend a rather unpleasant few minutes being stopped and questioned by store security.

Comment: @Traveller - there was no sign like this when traveled in Germany or at least I saw none. However, these signs can be seen all over the place where I live (Eastern-Europe EU country), thus the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks - to me (native English speaker) has  your question read as if the signs were in German stores

Comment: It's quite funny in Austria, the law says if you paid cash you have to take the receipt and carry it with you until you leave, but there's no penalty if you don't, which creates a bit of a weird situation.

Comment: @etarion - it kind of make sense since paying by card is traceable. Also, having laws without penalty is not that uncommon and generally, there are many reasons for having such laws as explained in [this great Politics answer here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26724/what-is-the-purpose-of-issuing-laws-regulations-without-penalty).

Comment: If you were supposed to take the receipt, they wouldn't have asked if you want it.

Comment: As a general rule if someone has asked you this it would be *extremely* unlikely that it was a legal requirement for you to take it - otherwise they'd just give it to you and not give you the illegal option of not taking it...

Comment: In Italy, I was told (in 2013) that the “Tax Police” (guardia di finanza) would sometimes ask a buyer outside the store for the receipt and that the _merchant_ could be in trouble if they didn’t have one.

Comment: @Chris Not really. In China merchants will go as far as to give you a discount or free goods in exchange for not receiving a receipt, in order to facilitate tax evasion.

Comment: In many cases (sadly), the asking for receipt is to remove the temptation faced by staff to just pocket your cash. Sole proprietors might also write off the stock and not declare the sale. If you are in a mall or shopping complex the landlord may also have rights to access sales data. N.B. this works for hotel staff who just do the room themselves as well.

Comment: In Sweden, there was a campaign telling customers that buy *Dagens lunch* (*lunch of the day*) at lunch restaurants to take their receipts; because many subsequent customers would order exactly the same, some restaurants would commit tax fraud by issuing only one receipt for x subsequent identical sales.

Comment: @user71659: Fair enough. Though I would imagine in that case it is them breaking the law rather than you though (since I assume the idea is to pocket some of the money and only pay tax on the smaller claimed amount). But the point stands that shopkeepers are not entirely legal people.

Comment: In Austria I get asked all the time if I want the receipt. As mentioned, I am required by law to take it.

Comment: @Traveller These signs are specific to Romania and are required by the government to combat tax evasion (unreported transactions by the merchant). It's not so that the customer can prove to the merchant that they paid for the goods.  It's also quite ridiculous as you will even see the signs on e.g. a food truck which you cannot even enter or exit as a customer.

Comment: I find the question strange as the requirement is fairly recent even in Romania, and widely ridiculed. I am unsure why OP would believe that such things are common in other countries.

Comment: @mckenzm: as the printout is available only with electronic cash registers, the sales are already registered before the question even arises.

Comment: @WGroleau: In Germany, tax officers can line up like a normal customer and look how things are run. Also, electronic cash registers have interfaces for the tax office, and a tax officer can ask to look into that at any time and wihtout advance notice. If there's anything suspicious, they can directly start an investigation. => this system is set up in a way that doesn't need the customer's receipt. The customer is the only one who may need the receipt.

Comment: "this happened after it was actually printed": Taking private receipts is fairly common in Germany ("so I know where my money went"; note that also paying cash is still very common). A store may find that many customers want/need the receipt and decide to automatically print the receipt. As for full invoice for deducting: as long as the bill is below 250 €, the cash register printout is good for deducting in Germany (they anyways have to list nowadays what was sold and how much of it) both VAT and as an expense.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It is perfectly normal to accept or reject the receipt if that is asked. It is slightly impolite to reject a receipt if it has been printed and handed out, since this slows the checkout line for everybody and since the sales clerk may not have a waste basket nearby.

- The **shop** is always required to keep records for tax purposes. Generally that means printing a receipt on a cash register which logs every transaction. These records don't include the printout for the customer because that would normally leave with the customer.
- The **customer** may be required to keep records for tax purposes, e.g. if the expense becomes a deductable business expense.
- Keeping the receipt would also provide clarity if there are accusations of shoplifting, but receipts are not the *only* way to resolve such a question. Just one of the most convienient.
- Having the receipt may be necessary if the customer wants to complain about having gotten wrong change.
- The receipt may be required for warranty claims.

So the customer can ditch the receipt immediately. Inconsiderate people may drop it on the sidewalk, so shops may ask routinely "do you want that" and drop it in a waste paper bin if not. I believe there are some models of cash register which can bypass the printing for the customer, while making all required records.

Comment: Yes, fortunately there are grocery stores which only print upon confirmation and thus reduce waste.

Comment: The issue with printing on demand is the time. For one they have to wait for the customer to respond and only after can start handling the next customer. Secondly when doing a bigger weekend sopping with many items printing it can take some notable amount of time. If printed while registering that however is no issue. I have seen multiple shops returning to print by default as apparently a notable amount of people want to have it. (I sometimes ask for it, when i have the impression they scanned wrongly, as checking the receipt is simpler than arguing - especially as I'm wrong most of the time)

Comment: The customer copy is evidence that the store is keeping a copy......

Comment: @johannes I am curious, how much time does it take to print a receipt? Surely it can't be much more than a few seconds?

Comment: @Berend even assuming one is 5 seconds you have to account that there is a number of clients every day, so those seconds can sum up to a nice few hours over a year. And that's a significant amount of time. Besides a mere waiting for the response can take more than 5 seconds.

Comment: @johannes, I see, we're really talking big money here :-)

Comment: Customers are easily getting impatient while waiting, when apparently hardly anything happens ...

Comment: *and since the sales clerk may not have a waste basket nearby.* That is an issue the clerk should take with the store owner. And why should this be a reason for me as a customer to get this problem in my hands? (The trash I don't need)

Comment: @Andreas, would you want to stand in line **behind** the guy who debates this issue with the clerk? I know I wouldn't.

Comment: It's nothing to debate about. If I don't want the receipt then it's up to the store to do what they want with it. It really isn't the customers problem. And what makes you think the customer has a handy waste bin in his/her pocket? It's the same as if someone hands you a flyer on the street, you have no obligation to accept it.

Answer (score 37):

It's absolutely *in Ordnung*. If you don't need it, you don't take it, as many people in Germany do.

Comment: Do you feel it's right to use German in an answer? I don't know any German and had to translate what you said.

Comment: @data even if you don't know what *in Ordnung* means, does the rest of the answer leave any room for ambiguity?

Comment: Is it really so hard to see "in Ordnung" probably means "in order" ?

Comment: @vikingsteve: And what does "in order" mean? (Have you ever heard an *English speaker* say "It's absolutely in order" to mean "It's absolutely fine"?) We can guess that *Ordnung* means "order", or that "in order" means "fine", but asking us to guess all these things at once is a bit much.

Comment: @ruakh "Everything is in order" should be perfectly understandable to an English speaker and usable in everyday speech. It's not a stretch to change that to "It's in order".

Comment: @user71659: It's not a stretch to change that to "It's in order", but it's a stretch to change it to "It's *in Ordnung*". Which is my point. There are only so many little guess-leaps that it's reasonable to expect the reader to make.

Answer (score 3):

In some countries it is apparently easier to evade paying taxes if you don't print a receipt for your income. In China for example, businesses for a time were required to get a special printer and print receipts on government issued numbered forms using a government issued software application and for a while these forms even had a scratch area that would reveal hidden prizes, in order to motivate customers to ask for that receipt. Nowadays it's more and more electronic though, and printed receipts are no longer required everywhere.

In Germany that is not the case. Taxes are only based on the businesses own records, and a copy of the receipt given to the customer is such a record; however, whether you keep your copy is irrelevant. The records have to be complete. Every transaction has to be recorded, and skipping transactions can likely be found in a tax-audit.

Though I don't know if it is actually harder to cheat in Germany, or if it is simply done so rarely as to not be an issue.

Comment: Customer receipt is not a record of anything in Germany. Shops have their own merchant receipts which are always printed or stored digitally regardless of buyers' wish to have or not to have their receipts.

Comment: I believe that is only partially correct. When a business *does* have an electronic cash register, this must meet certain standards. If not, they must document their daily manual count.

Comment: **Untaken receipts have potential.** For some commodities, e.g. car fuel, the shop assistant may collect receipts not taken by customers and then sell them for tax evasion purposes. For example small businesses may purchase such receipts to claim (false) expenses (fuel which they did not actually buy) and then list car rides which actually never happened and this way make their taxable income lower. So for such commodities, taking the receipt can be a small contribution to prevent the behavior.

Comment: @miroxlab: I'd think the resale value of these receipts is low: how much would you pay for a fuel receipt considering that you could just take one of your own private fuel receipts? (Besides, AFAIK the German tax office works on the premise that no properly kept vehicle log exists, so that  will probably be the very first to be questioned and subject to an estimate). The same holds for pretty much all other goods on such "Kleinbetragsrechnungen" for stuff where the customer may not take their receipt (i.e. nothing with warranty/possibilty to return etc.)

Comment: @cbeleites – OK, but if you purchase uncollected receipts for let's say 10000€ for fuel or for building materials (another favorite commodity for this practice), it is a volume what you normally would not get from your private use. On internet you can see some ads selling them which shows this is what some people actually do.

Comment: @miroxlav: what price would they be?

Comment: @cbeleites – I don't know, but quick search did show they start at 1% of their actual value. Maybe depends on their purpose. (Decreasing taxable income, evidence of spent money for construction works in order to get construction-related loans etc.) But I found that unclaimed invoices are sold, too.

Comment: @miroxlav: so far, the one business case here that I find convincing is that the *seller* of these receipts does gain something (note: the fact that I get, say, academic conference spam doesn't show that that conference is of any real value for me - it just shows that the seller expects to be able to find dupes). The buyer would need them to be < 250 € to work: above their business would need to be named on the receipt. Say, 166 € on average. So the buyer needs to cook their books to make at least different 60 cases look plausible in context. 10 k building materials may be hidden for a ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92834/discussion-between-cbeleites-and-miroxlav).

Comment: This was slighty changed in 2020

Answer (score 2):

I live in Munich and receipts here are generally printed on-demand, i.e. the cashier asks if you need the receipt and if the answer is yes, he will print it for you. But:

- Now-defunct grocery chain *Tengelmann* used to put up signs suggesting that customers don't take a receipt if not needed to save the environment.
- Waiting for the receipt to be printed may increase waiting time for the people behind you in the queue.

Hence it is perfectly fine not to take the receipt.

Comment: Nowadays, the receipt printers are quite fast.

Comment: @glglgl True, but usually the cashier is already moving to grip the next customers groceries, so he has to stop his current motion, focus on the register in front of him, push the button to have the receipt printed and most of the time, he also hands me the receipt or at least tries to if I'm not faster to grab it ...

Answer (score 2):

In Germany, this is perfectly alright, especially in a "fancy store".

The receipt is obviously needed should you ever want to return a good (hardly the case with chocolate), though in a "fancy store", your word of honour is normally enough anyway (also, shop assistants will immediately recognize your face and know what you bought -- even after weeks, not sure how they do that, it's scary). Not so in "mass" shops. No receipt, no return, no warranty.

You may want to keep the receipt (and in particular, not throw it away in front of the store!) just in case because there exist singular cases where people have gotten in trouble due to scammers. Some 10 or so years ago, it reportedly happened rather often that someone would pick up your receipt at a supermarket, and then stop you while you were loading stuff into your car, call police and claim you stole their goods (providing the receipt as evidence).
I'm doubtful about whether that would actually hold in court, especially since it's pretty obvious from surveillance tapes and from your credit card bill that you paid for the goods. But reportedly, scammers were often successful with that (maybe also because people didn't want to risk a criminal charge?). Well, whatever, that's that. It's easy to avoid that possibility by just taking the receipt with you.

You may want to keep the receipt because some (not all) shops print more or less obscure transaction data, and sometimes data that can be used to identify you or your card on the receipt. If your paranoia level isn't above threshold for that, it's no issue.

You may also want to keep the receipt as a proof of ownerships in some stores where the cash point is very far from the exit. Otherwise, an overzealous in-house detective may become a nuisance if you can't present the receipt (though it has never happened to me, personally).

Nowadays, most stores do not print the receipt at all if you say "No" after they ask you REWE being an obnoxious exception: They ask, and you say "No", they still print it, and put it under the table quickly afterwards, but then make a vexed face when you say: *"OK, now that you printed it anyway, I'll take it with me."*.

In other places, by not taking the receipt you risk severe trouble, notably in the German-speaking northern part of Italy (Alto Adige). Eat in a restaurant, pay your bill, fail to take the receipt, and walk away. A hundred meters down the road, police stops you, and you're in real trouble as accomplice in a tax fraud.

Answer (score -4):

I have encountered some cases where if I have paid with a credit card, the business may charge a higher amount to the card than what was authorized.

Sellers know that memory is fallible and without a receipt I may be unlikely to accurately remember the correct amount of the charge to check my credit card statement, especially if the amount they actually charge is not extravagantly higher.  They also know that even in the unlikely case I do remember all the details, do check, and notice that they've charged more, I don't have a copy of the receipt to be able to contradict the credit card statement or practically win a dispute through the credit card company.

If I do take the receipt, I have the capacity to check it against the credit card statement and contest any overcharge, and the business knows this.  If the business is invested in keeping a low-level fraud going without detection for as long as possible (so as to maximize profits from the activity), the business will only apply the overcharge to customers who declined to take receipts.

Thus, even if I never actually do check that transaction, I am more protected from this kind of fraud than I would be if I refused the receipt.  Paying cash offers even stronger protection against later changes to the amount.

---

I have seen cases in which a shopkeeper allows someone to purchase an item with cash without accepting a receipt and attempt to leave, then accuses the customer of stealing.  The customer might be offered the choice of (a) arrest and a trip to the local jail while the details are sorted out, or (b) paying some amount of money, often related to the total asking price for the goods they were attempting to leave with, and/or the amount of remaining cash the shopkeeper knows the customer has.  Due to the monetary and nonmonetary costs associated with (a), many people will choose (b), or at least a negotiated version of (b) with a lower cost than initially demanded.

Again, a business invested in keeping this racket going will only pick targets who don't have a receipt they can use as defense evidence.

(I've also seen the version where a seller of expensive small things, like jewels/jewelry, will take out many samples to show a prospective customer, and then if the customer doesn't buy, the seller will put everything away, pocketing/hiding one of the items when the non-customer's distracted, then "discover" it missing and accuse the non-customer of stealing.  A receipt won't help in that case, though.)

---

I have seen cases where it is important to get a receipt from a service business (e.g. short-term bicycle rental) especially when paying cash, because the employees might pocket the funds and underreport sales to their employer, making the customer who doesn't take the receipt an unwitting assistant to theft from the business they may be trying to support.  This seems less likely when a recording electronic cash register or electronic payment is used, but such registers aren't universal, and if you declare that you don't want the receipt your transaction might not be processed through a recording register.

In my understanding, this was the original purpose for the receipt, allowing a customer to notify the business owner to be on the lookout for those funds in the business's cash box, helping keep employees honest whether or not that notice actually occurred for any particular transaction.  I have never seen such notice happen in practice, even while the fraud it is intended to prevent does.

---

Businesses may be more likely to conduct low-level fraud against tourists, who are much less likely than locals to return to the vendor for future business even if everything goes well, and less likely to be able/willing to take any action in the legal system of the jurisdiction they are visiting.

I believe these kinds of dishonest treatment are less likely to happen in Germany than in some other places, and do not believe a customer generally has any legal *duty* to accept the receipt (unless they plan to e.g. claim the purchase as a tax deduction), but I find accepting the receipt to be generally good practice.

---

If you are purchasing durable goods with a warranty, you may need the receipt to prove the date of purchase and amount paid *for that item*, which a credit card statement might not show as clearly.

If you purchased an expensive commodity and then see the same item cheaper from another vendor shortly thereafter, AND your credit card is one of the few offering a cross-vendor price-match program which covers the purchased item, you would need your receipt to make a claim under that program.

If you plan to cross a customs-controlled border with the goods you are purchasing, you may legally need the receipt to prove the value of the goods in order to demonstrate that your imports are under a duty-free exemption and/or reduce the probability that your duties will be assessed on a value higher than your recent market price for that item.  This is less important for consumables you will eat/use before departing.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: all these incidents happened in shops in Germany?

Comment: @user2705196 Nope.  As noted, I would expect them to be less likely there, but wouldn't bet on the actual rate being exactly *zero* even in Germany.  It's a relatively large and populous country.

Comment: -1 for giving a misleading impression of what is plausible in Germany.

Comment: Downvoting because the question was "Is it OK if I do not take the receipt in Germany?" and your answer reads like OP would be mad to even consider it. I'm not saying that these things *can't* happen, but they're **very** unlikely to be faced in Germany. You mention that they're "less likely to happen in Germany than in some other places" but to me that seems a significantly weaker statement than is merited given the context, and it's buried in the 11th paragraph of your answer.

Comment: I almost never take receipts these days, since I see any electronic payments on my debit statement and know how much cash I spend via math (cash withdrawn - cash currently in pocket), but I've never been the victim of, or have even heard of anyone being the victim of such scams around here.

Comment: @Magisch ...that you know of.  The first one could easily have happened to you without you paying enough attention to catch it.   Also keep in mind that because of how SE works, others with the same question but in other countries are likely to be pointed here.  These same scams and frauds that are possible in one country are possible in others; it's a question of relative frequency. I also don't think you can pretend that Germany just doesn't have any criminals/fraudsters, even if rule of law is relatively strong. This post is about what's *possible* even if not *probable*, +the last section.

Comment: @WBT That's untrue. The debit cash terminals display exactly what is being charged to your card, down to the cent, at the point of sale. Transactions are not authorized unless confirmed by PIN, so unless they also somehow found out my debit pin, there is no way for them to overcharge after the fact.

Comment: @Magisch If OP is a traveler from another country, OP (or someone else with the same question) might not have a chip-and-PIN card. Chip-and-PIN combined with good practices like not letting a card out of your sight and only ever using terminals that are unmodified originals from the bank (good luck getting a 100% accurate recognition rate) provides a lot of protection, but it's not *completely* foolproof & doesn't provide protection in all the listed cases, especially the last section (which applies even if there's *never* any merchant fraud).

Comment: Signature only credit card payments without a POS card machine are practically gone in Germany. There is always a card machine involved. If you pay by credit card in a restaurant, they will bring you a card machine. US-style carrying the card away is not practised at all. And of course there are still lots of places that will simply not take your credit card because the fees are too high for them to bother with, as the locals have Maestro cards with chip and pin for debit, which is much cheaper.

Comment: The suggestion that transactions are not authorised unless confirmed by PIN is incorrect -- many transactions are contactless and therefore don't require a PIN

Comment: @JohnMacLeod: Not sure what you mean by "contactless", but it's true that especially for smaller sums, whether I have to enter a PIN, (maybe rarely) sign somewhere, or do neither seems pretty much random.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper [Contactless payment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contactless_payment) took a bit longer to take hold in Germany than in a lot of other developed countries, but it's very widely accepted now (at least in Hamburg and Berlin, I'd assume other major urban areas are similar).

Comment: @ChrisH: Ah, I suspected that's what was meant. But how does it "[not] require a PIN"? I use it regularly, and the display on the device will occasionally ask me for my PIN, same as when I still used to put in the card into the slot.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper normally it asks for your PIN on transactions over a certain amount (I think 25 or 30 EUR, but it might vary from bank to bank). On smaller transactions it *can* ask for a PIN, but that's extremely rare in my experience. I've never made a non-contactless card payment (offline) without being asked for either a PIN or a signature.

Comment: Everything in this answer might be good advise for shopping in more corrupt countries, but except for maybe the last three paragraphs they are all very implausible scenarios in Germany. Source: I am living in Germany for all my life.